# Why yarn install gives typescript error from dependency after react-native-clean project

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg, react-native-webview

I cleaned my react native project with react-native-clean-project. After that yarn install gives this error:

```
warning ../../../../../../package.json: No license field
$ yarn tsc
warning ../../../../../../package.json: No license field
$ /Users/username/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6/.tmp/81343329c03468d8a899f4bb8612d8b8.0999079ce5055d5008e3c67ffe97b2756c0c741f.prepare/node_modules/.bin/tsc
src/WebView.android.tsx:340:7 - error TS2605: JSX element type 'NativeWebViewAndroid' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/username/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
      Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.

340       <NativeWebView
          ~~~~
341         key="webViewKey"
    ~~~~
...
356         {...nativeConfig.props}
    ~~~~~~~
357       />
    ~~
```

I try to clean yarn cache, install yarn again but seems no effect. Any suggestions ?